# what does pg_total_relation_size do behind the scenes?

Tags: postgresql

I'd be curious how `pg_total_relation_size` does its magic? Is it using expensive operations like table scans or very lightweigt operations like asking the file system for file sizes? The [postgres documentation on the function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) does unfortunately not mention that aspect of the function. If it is expensive, is there a cheaper way?

Comment: The source will tell you [dbsize.c](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/dbsize_8c_source.html) search for `calculate_relation_size`. You can also search for `pg_total_relation_size` to see how it gets to `calculate_relation_size`.

Comment: tyvm for pointing me to the source. it seems that pg_total_relation_size entirely relies on file sizes and does no deep scanning of the file contents.